# How to delete object and list elements whose name or key end with string using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

Given a yaml file I would like to remove all objects whose key ends with "Test" and also all array values that end with "Test" independent of the depth (recursively)

#Input

```yaml
project: A project name
targets:
  targetA:
    name: "target A"
    path: "/some/path"
    sources:
      - "Source A"
      - "Source B"
      - "Source with Test"

  targetATest:
    name: "target A test"
    path: "/some/path"
    sources:
      - "Source A"
      - "Source B"
```

#Output

```yaml
project: A project name
targets:
  targetA:
    name: "target A"
    path: "/some/path"
    sources:
      - "Source A"
      - "Source B"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried a lot of variations of `select` with `key` like `yq -i 'del(.. | select(tag == "!!map") | select(key | tag == "!!str"))'` and test("") but with no success

Comment: Always add your attempts in your questions. Click `edit` and add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried a lot of variations of `select` with `key` like `yq -i 'del(.. | select(tag == "!!map") | select(key | tag == "!!str"))'` and test("") but with no success

A straightforward solution using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) and your failed approach would be to separately test both your criteria:

```bash
del(.. | select(
  (tag == "!!str" and test("Test$")) or
  (key | select(tag == "!!str") | test("Test$"))
))
```

```yaml
project: A project name
targets:
  targetA:
    name: "target A"
    path: "/some/path"
    sources:
      - "Source A"
      - "Source B"
```